# leaflet - point on the map moves when zoom in and out

Tags: r, google-maps, leaflet, zooming

I used `leaflet` package to creates a map widget, and then added two layers with the function `addMarkers()`. However, I found that the points on the map change their positions when zoom in and out. The relative scripts are as following:

First, create a function `pchIcons` with r shapes in `leaflet`

```
pchIcons <- function(pch = 0:14, width = 30, height = 30, col = 1:15, ...) {
  pchLength <- length(pch)
  pchFiles <- character(pchLength)

  # create a sequence of png images
  for (i in seq_len(pchLength)) {
    pchTempFile <- tempfile(fileext = '.png')
    png(pchTempFile, width = width, height = height, bg = 'transparent')
    par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
    plot.new()
    points(.5, .5, pch = pch[i], cex = 1.5, col = col[i], ...)
    dev.off()
    pchFiles[i] = pchTempFile
  }
  pchFiles
}
```

Then create a base layer with Paris' position, and add two layers, each layer represents one group.

```
baseLayer <- leaflet(zero) %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner") %>%
  setView(posParis[["lng"]], posParis[["lat"]], zoom = 12)

addZeroLayer <- baseLayer %>%
  addMarkers(popup = paste(paste(zero$Code, zero$Ecart),
                           zero$Address,
                           sep = "<br/>"),
             lng = as.numeric(zero$Long),
             lat = as.numeric(zero$Lat),
             icon = ~ icons(
               iconUrl = pchIcons(rep(magasinEcart[1], nrow(zero)),
                                  40,
                                  40,
                                  col = colorZero,
                                  lwd = 2)
             ),
         group = '0')

addOneLayer <- addZeroLayer %>%
  addMarkers(popup = paste(paste(one$Code, one$Ecart),
                           one$Address,
                           sep = "<br/>"),
             lng = as.numeric(one$Long),
             lat = as.numeric(one$Lat),
             icon = ~ icons(
               iconUrl = pchIcons(rep(magasinEcart[2], nrow(one)),
                                  40,
                                  40,
                                  col = colorOne,
                                  lwd = 2)
             ),
         group = '1')
```

Next, add UI controls to switch layers on and off with `addLayersControl()` and add legend with `addLegend()`.

```
mapTourist <- addOneLayer %>%
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c('0', '1'),
                   options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright",
            pal = colorFactor(brewer.pal(9, 'Set1')[3:4],
                              unique(magasinBaseComp$Ecart)),
            values = names(magasinEcart),
            title = "Ecart",
            opacity = 1)
```

Finally, we can find that when zoom in or out, the points on map moves (as screenshots show).[image: zoom out]
[image: zoom in]

Does someone know what's the problem and how could I solve it? Any idea is welcomed!

Comment: The map is dynamically changing when you zoom. I believe the points are in the same spot, the road detail is just changing.

Comment: Not sure, we can take google map as an example: when we zoom in/out, the position of spot doesn't change.

Comment: Do not know the syntax for `R`, but you probably need to specify the [`iconAnchor`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#icon-iconanchor) correctly. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222971/how-can-i-prevent-leaflet-from-moving-my-marker-while-zooming-into-the-map/223056#223056